# Finding a function for the duration of daylight

Tags: trigonometry

I have to find a function
$$f(x)=a\sin(bx+c)+d$$
where $f$ is, in hours, the duration of a daylight. I know in the summer solstice, this duration - which is the maximum - is 14 hours and in the winter solstice (which is the minimum), 9 hours.

The question requests to be $x=0$ the spring equinox and each season lasts 90 days. Therefore
$$f(90)=14,\qquad f(270)=9$$
Using this data, I could find the values of $a,b,c$ and $d$. However, the duration of a year should be 365 days.

Since for $x=90$, $f$ has its max value, then
$$\sin(90b+c)=1\Rightarrow90b+c=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and using the same idea
$$\sin(270b+c)=-1\Rightarrow270b+c=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
My question is, since the year has 365 days, how do I work with this arcs? I mean, should I  use the following equations instead:
$$90b+c=\frac{\pi}{2}\div365$$
$$270b+c=\frac{3\pi}{2}\div365$$

Comment: $4$ seasons of $90$ days making a full year ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, I thought about it, but it's like that in the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the suggested division in your last two lines; I think a different model is called for. One adapted model is $$f(x)=a\sin\left(\frac{360}{365}bx+c\right)+d.$$